# How to resample the raster cells to make a merge (mosaic)?

Tags: python, rasterio

I am creating a DEM with raster files, but I would like to downsample the pixel values (resampling to lower resolution/larger cell sizes) in order to reduce the size of my generated file. My idea is to do this using the least amount of memory possible. My code is working fine for mosaic, without the downsampling. And I found this [documentation for Resampling](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html), but I didn't figure out how to insert the code sample in the mosaic code.

```
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

layers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for layer in layers:
  # files to merge into the DEM. 
  files = ['example1.zip', 'example2.zip', 'example3.zip', 'example4.zip'] # In my real problem, each layer has different files.
  files_path = '/content/raster'

  src_files_to_mosaic = []
  if not os.path.exists('/content/'+layer+'.tif'):
    for grade in list(set(files)):
      q = os.path.join(files_path, grade) #path of each grid
      raster_path = 'zip://'+q+'!'+grade[:8]+'.tif'# extract zip
      print(raster_path)
      src = rasterio.open(raster_path) # open each raster
      src_files_to_mosaic.append(src) #joins the paths to do the mosaic

    mosaic, out_trans = merge(src_files_to_mosaic)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy() # Copy the metadata
    # Update the metadata
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                    "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                    "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                    "transform": out_trans,
                    "crs": "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs",                    
                    }
                    )
    # Plot the result
    show(mosaic, cmap='terrain')
    # Write the mosaic raster to disk
    raster_name = '/content/'+layer+'.tif'
    with rasterio.open(raster_name, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
      dest.write(mosaic)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hello @IanTurton! Thank you for the welcome! Should I edit my question? I tried to insert the piece of code from [Resampling documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html) into the code that I entered in the question. However, I was very distant from any success and preferred not to add the attempts.

Comment: I could reduce the resolution of each tile before going to the mosaic process, but doing that I will use memory and much space in disk... it is what I want to avoid.